# What does this regexp pattern mean?

Tags: regex, actionscript

I'm working with some Action Script file and I found this:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /.*\//  
var results:Array = pattern.exec(cardImageService.url);
```

I know it's a regular expression and that `exec()` is looking for my pattern in my string. But how should I understand this pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: The "Regular expression Tester" says: The entered string is not a regular expression!

Comment: @Robalot - That might depend on your regex engine, specifically whether the delimiters and escape character are being properly understood.

Answer (score 3):

```
/   - Regex delimiter

.   - Meta-character to match any character except newline.
*   - Quantifier for zero or more
\/  - A literal /. Since / is used as a delimiter, to match a literal / we 
      need to escape it.

/   - Regex delimiter
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern

```
.*\/
```

means

```
.*      # any character (except \n), zero or more times
\/      # the forward slash "/"
```

The forward slash must be escaped because when written as a regex literal (like in your case), the forward slash is already in use to delimit the regex.

In other cases, when the regex is presented as a string, it would look like `".*/"` and mean the same thing.

Effectively, this matches a path up to (and including) the last forward slash.

```
/some/very/long/path/with.a.file
-------match---------
```

Answer (score 1):

It matches any number of characters (zero or more), ending with a `/` character. Typically, this will grab everything in the string from the beginning until (and including) the last forward slash in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the RegEx delimiter

`.*` selects 0 or more characters (as many as possible), excluding newlines

`\/` is an escape character followed by `/` so that it will match the `/` char without ending the regex

`/` is the other RegEx delimiter

what this regex will search for is any number of characters followed by a `/` char.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` means find anything, any number of times (0 to infinite) and `\/` means find a slash, the `\` is an escape character. In essence, the regex would match pretty much any line that has a / in it.